# custom Value class for a custom Linked List in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to make a custom `Node` class for a custom `LinkedList`. The `Node` should contain a `value` and a reference to another `Node` object.

```
public class Node {
   Value value;
   Node nextNode;
   public Node(Value value, Node nextNode) {
       this.value = value;
       this.nextNode = nextNode;
   }

}
```

how do I make this `Value` class so that it can get `value` of any datatype of user's choice ?

Comment: Use Generic Type Params

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a Value class. You can use a generic type parameter :

```
public class Node<T> {
   T value;
   Node nextNode;
   public Node(T value, Node nextNode) {
       this.value = value;
       this.nextNode = nextNode;
   }
}
```

Your `LinkedList` class should also have a type parameter :

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;
    ...
}
```